# Как создать GUI для консольного приложения?

Tags: windows, gui

Написал антивирус на Visual С++ консольного типа. Теперь не знаю, на чем же
все таки создать для него GUI интерфейс. Перебрал несколько вариантов.

1. Перенести на C++ Builder т.е там легко можно создать GUI - но как вы знате 
   тогда антивирус будет сильно тормозить из за паскалевской VCL да и вообще как то не принято на билдере бистрые программы писать.
2. Использовать MFC - вручную инициализировать интерфейс мазохизм а дилоговые окна не позволяют строить красивый интерфейс.
3. Использовать WindowForms вместе со своим неуправляемым кодом - но при этом также оооочень сильно потеряю в быстродествии из за того что часть кода будет исполняться на .NET машине.

QT - тоже не выход. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Куда ни глянешь - везде мрак и беспросветность...

Answer (score 5):

Пока вы так сидите и **рассуждаете о быстродействии,** другие люди сидят и **пишут программы**. И на билдере, и на `.net'e`, практикуют `rapid development`, и ничего не тормозит, и все здорово работает.

Тем более, если вы работаете над антивирусом, то, очевидно, что быстродействие `GUI` - это совершенно не главное и тормозное ядро убьет все преимущества быстрого интерфейса.

*Короче говоря, берите то, что вам больше всего знакомо или используйте `random(1 -> 3)` для выбора пункта и начинайте делать.* Лично я бы выбрал бы `Qt` или `Windows Forms` с маршаллингом основного кода из `dllки`.

Answer (score 3):

А Вы уверены, что GUI вообще будет тормозить работу этого приложения? Можно сам код, который осуществляет основные функции антивируса: поиск, анализ, лечение и т.д. - запихнуть в библиотеку, отдельно написать GUI на чем хотите и к нему подключить эту DLL. Графические элементы могут тормозить, когда их активно используют, когда в них что-то добавляется, перерисовывается и т.д. У вас основной функционал с этим не связан. Поэтому главную часть пишите в VC++, а гуй - в чем хотите.

Answer (score 2):

Не принято на билдере писать быстрые программы? Да, некоторые личности так дамают. 
Если все правильно написать, то и на .нет не будет тормозить. Поэтому, мой совет, если знаете vcl, напишите на нем. А вот если будет тормозить, перепишите на другой технологии - заодно и сравните.

Но главное не забывать, что нужно писать красиво - миллион строк, добавляемых в мемо тормозить будет кругом, если только не принять мер.

Comment: Думаю, как ни крутись, а по-настоящему быстрого приложения только на .net не напишешь. Устроена так...

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как у Вас организовано консольное приложение. Но если предположить, что все команды (параметры запуска) можно описать одной строкой - то можно создать GUI и из него создавать новый процесс (вызывать вашу консоль) и передавать на вход (в ф-ю main) требуемые данные.

Comment: Можно, но если нужно, чтобы отображался ход работы (пополнялся список обнаруженных вирусов, прогресс поиска, текущий файл и т.д.), то таким способ сделать будет несколько затруднительно. Все равно придется переписывать консольное приложение. Лучше основной функционал запихнуть в DLL, и подключать ее как в консольное приложение, так и в графическое.

Answer (score 0):

> оооочень сильно потеряю в быстродествии из за того что часть кода будет исполняться на .NET машине.

Проводил тесты, тестируемая программа (вычисление простых чисел решетом Эрастофена) на C# работала на 10% медленнее, чем на C++. Но когда переписал код на указатели, производительность стала такой же, как у C++. Это значит, что управляемый код работает практически с той же скоростью. Поэтому можешь смело выбирать третий вариант.

> QT - тоже не выход.

Почему? Все вроде нахваливают, хотя сам не использовал.